# ¿Cómo puedo pasar de un entry a otro en python (tkinter) pulsando la tecla Enter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quisiera saber cómo podría pasar de un entry a otro en python tkinter usando la tecla Enter. Tengo una app sencilla que calcula 4 valores cada uno pedidos en un entry diferente, quisiera pasar de un entry a otro usando Enter y cuando todos los campos estén llenos pulsar la misma tecla Enter para calcular los 4 números.

Comment: Si agregas el código de lo que hayas intentado o al que debería acoplarse la solución tendrás más chances de obtener una respuesta.

Comment: "cual sería el código" estas pidiendo un código o ayuda? Te recomiendo que no des la impresión de que queres que te hagan el trabajo. Y también te recomiendo agregar una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerzo (como una lista de algunos links visitados y/o un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se nada de tu código, por lo que voy a hacer una demo para que sepas como hacerlo:

```
import tkinter as tk

def funcEnter(event):
    #el metodo focus_set() simplemente hace que el mouse se vaya al segundo entry
    Entry2.focus_set()

root=tk.Tk()

Entry1=tk.Entry(root)

#el metodo bind es un metodo que al realizar un evento, ya sea presionar
#enter o mover el mouse, ejecuta una funcion indicada,tiene dos parametros:
#  "<Return>" indica la tecla enter 
#  la funcion indicada arriba, funcEnter

Entry1.bind("<Return>",funcEnter)
Entry1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=3,pady=3)

Entry2=tk.Entry(root)
Entry2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=3,pady=3)

root.mainloop()
```

recuerda esto es una demo por lo que tendras que adaptarlo a tu codigo.
La proxima vez intenta mostrar algo de codigo o algun inteto de ello. Espero ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente funciona, sin embargo me cuesta un poco aún adaptarlo a mi código que está como objeto.

Comment: @DiegoALR edita esta pregunta o crea una nueva pregunta con la clase.

Comment: Ya pude lograrlo, muchas gracias!